# Can I remote login to Microsoft's Windows with the command line?

Tags: command-line

I can connect to Gnu/Linux machines from Microsoft's Windows (and Gnu/Linux to Gnu/Linux) using PuTTY/ssh. I want to do the other way round - connect to a Windows machine from Gnu/Linux  only command line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes your Gnu/Linux machine will be more than happy to do this. You just need to run a ssh server on the Microsoft Windows machine, with an appropriate shell.

I know that this can be done for bash on MS-Windows: using WSL (A Gnu/Linux sub-system for MS-Windows, but without the Linux ), Cygwin, or Mingu.

Microsoft has [more info on setting up ssh server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), for both `cmd`, and power-shell.

Comment: It's worth to note that if you run WSL, you can just spin up a SSH server inside and it will work.

Comment: @Panki Do you then have access to the MS-Windows host?

Comment: yes, I can even run `cmd.exe` or work on the filesystem.

Comment: @Panki you should add that as an answer.

Comment: Nah, I think your edit describes it well enough :)

Comment: I agree with your answer, but would recommend updating the SSH link to point to [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) on Microsoft's GitHub, as the Add Feature version is not an up-to-date version of OpenSSH (current version is 8.0.0.0p1, versus Add Features' 0.0.1.0)

Comment: @JW0914 do the edit. I am not the expert here.